# Input select2 remove selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Good Morning,

I have:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('select[id$="cbxLocal"]').select2({ placeholder: 'Selecione primeiro uma solicitação', allowClear: true });


                $('#cbxLocal').select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "../Servico/Local.ashx",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: function (term, page) {

                            return {
                                q: term,
                                idTipoLocal: idTipoLocal,
                                trazerEndereco: 1
                            };
                        },
                        results: function (bond, page) {
                            return {
                                results: bond.results
                            };
                        }
                    },
                    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                    minimumInputLength: 3,
                    //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                    //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                });

            });
            
             function limparTodosCampos() {

            $('select[id$="cbxLocal"]').select2({ placeholder: 'Selecione', allowClear: false, data: null });

        }
```

```html
<label id="divCbxLocal" class="cbxLocal">
  <span>Local</span>
  <input id="cbxLocal" name="cbxLocal" class="select2" type="text" />
</label>
 <fieldset>
    <input id="btLimpar" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="limparTodosCampos()" />
            </fieldset>
```

And I want reset the value selected by javascript. 
When I click the "Clear" button, I want to clear the value that the user selected in the combobox (select2)
How I do? The version select2 is 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Include your jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to clear the input field's value? The question wasn't very clear. If so, you can use this code (uses JQuery):

```
$(function() {
  $('.signup-btn').click(function() {
    $('.signup input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
});
```

This code example shows how to clear a text field, wrapped in a "signup" class, when a button with the class "signup-btn" is clicked.

Comment: I edited the example to contain a full code sample. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to clarify :)

Comment: It did not work, in the input work with select2 (jquery), it works like combobox.